# How to initilize logAspectj without using spring

Tags: spring, aspectj

I am following [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/) and trying to implement aspectj without using spring or maven build.

In aspectj with spring implementation I see aspect class is loaded to this bean id **logAspect**

```
<bean id="logAspect" class="com.mkyong.aspect.LoggingAspect" />
```

If I want to load this manually using a java class without spring. To which interface or class I should create this implementation and how to load it so that aspect logging works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AspectJ is completely independent of Spring. Try not to think "how to use AspectJ without Spring" but rather just "how to use AspectJ". Having said that, I recommend the AspectJ homepage. There you will find documentation and introductory material like the [programming guide](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/index.html). It even contains samples for tracing, logging, profiling. Using AspectJ without Spring is actually much simpler than with Spring.

If you use the [AspectJ Development Tools (AJDT)](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/) from within Eclipse, you get several code samples with the installation, again including tracing/logging. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the Programming guide link. It was very helpful.